# Why is my test hadoop code that connects to libhdfs throwing a Segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, hadoop, segmentation-fault

I'm using libhdfs to connect and write into an hdfs system. The program works fine, however when I attach GDB to it, It segfaults in hdfsConnect, but the connection goes through and I'm able to write into the hdfs system. However sometimes, the connection does not happen. The seg fault is bothering me. Here is the code and the GDB BT.

```
#include "/home/hadoop_from_source/hdfs.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>

int main (int arg, char* args[]) {

    hdfsFS hdfsFs = hdfsConnect("172.19.108.136",9000);

    if (hdfsFs != NULL)
        std:: cout << "Success" << std::endl;
    else
        std:: cout << "Fail " << std::endl;
}
```

The compiling and linking:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.o -lhdfs -L .
```

GDB:

```
451     struct hdfsBuilder *bld = hdfsNewBuilder();
(gdb) 
452     if (!bld)
(gdb) 
451     struct hdfsBuilder *bld = hdfsNewBuilder();
(gdb) 
452     if (!bld)
(gdb) 
454     hdfsBuilderSetNameNode(bld, host);
(gdb) 
455     hdfsBuilderSetNameNodePort(bld, port);
(gdb) 
456     return hdfsBuilderConnect(bld);
(gdb) 
457 }
(gdb) 
456     return hdfsBuilderConnect(bld);
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7df1e98 in hdfsBuilderConnect@plt () from ./libhdfs.so.0.0.0
(gdb) 
Single stepping until exit from function hdfsBuilderConnect@plt,
which has no line number information.
0x00007ffff7df1df8 in ?? () from ./libhdfs.so.0.0.0
(gdb) nexti
0x00007ffff7df1dfe in ?? () from ./libhdfs.so.0.0.0
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146c0 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146c4 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146c8 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146cd in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146d2 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146d7 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146dc in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146e1 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146e6 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146eb in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146f0 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146f5 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146f8 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f0146fd in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f014702 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f014707 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f01470c in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f014711 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f014716 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f01471a in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
0x000000302f01471e in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) 
hdfsBuilderConnect (bld=0x601370)
    at /home/hadoop-2.2.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/native/libhdfs/hdfs.c:563
563 {
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7df8385  563 {
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7df838a  563 {
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7df838d  563 {
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7df8392  563 {
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7df8397  563 {
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7df839c  563 {
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7df83a1  563 {
(gdb) 
565     jobject jConfiguration = NULL, jFS = NULL, jURI = NULL, jCachePath = NULL;
(gdb) 
566     jstring jURIString = NULL, jUserString = NULL;
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7df83c0  566     jstring jURIString = NULL, jUserString = NULL;
(gdb) 
575     env = getJNIEnv();
(gdb) 
[New Thread 0x7ffff2e41700 (LWP 7488)]
.
.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff3ca99b5 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```